# Where is my boot directory?

Tags: linux, boot, chrome-os, chrome-book

After going into developer mode on my Chromebook, I noticed something odd:

```
chronos@localhost / $ ls /
bin  debugd  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  postinst  proc  root  run  sbin  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

There wasn't any `/boot` directory.  It appears that all computers(not just linux) need the `/boot` directory, so where is it?

**Edit** contents of `/proc/cmdline`:

```
cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=9c4a8b66-bf2d-8344-b395-cc24c0f465ca/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=9c4a8b66-bf2d-8344-b395-cc24c0f465ca/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=f87508f343f6f7337752889bd7396a0593e694ed salt=52dd62128026d20e8cef890d18bfba577ebe23347e2ae6a12816d1e910cae197" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=9c4a8b66-bf2d-8344-b395-cc24c0f46
```

Comment: All operating systems need a way to boot, however /boot is not a universal solution to that.  You might want to read this, https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/disk-format - which describes the disk format including the boot approach.

Comment: What's the output of `cat /proc/cmdline` ?

Comment: May be on other partition?

Comment: It may not be mounted anymore. You do need to boot from somewhere, but after that, the boot process remounts the root filesystem and others anyway, and it may not mount the boot partition as it's no longer needed (and it's safer, OS's meant for widespread public wher majority of users have no clue what they are doing, tend to hide everything, lately even the file system itself, operating only on abstract collections of files with no known location).

Comment: @SHW `cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=9c4a8b66-bf2d-8344-b395-cc24c0f465ca/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=9c4a8b66-bf2d-8344-b395-cc24c0f465ca/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=f87508f343f6f7337752889bd7396a0593e694ed salt=52dd62128026d20e8cef890d18bfba577ebe23347e2ae6a12816d1e910cae197" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=9c4a8b66-bf2d-8344-b395-cc24c0f46`

Comment: @SHW `5ca add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic `

Comment: @ElliotA.much better to edit your original question and paste that output into it, rather than as comments.  Helps when people search for similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears that all computers(not just linux) need the /boot directory, so where is it?

No that's not true. Androids have a partition where the kernel is stored, a recovery partition (a fallback kernel?), a root partition and then some. Some projects use the recovery option to implement dual boot functionality, the Chrome OS developers extended this scheme and added a kernel partition A, a root partition A, kernel partition B, a root partition B and reserved space for kernel partition C, a root partition C as documented in [disk-format](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/disk-format).

There is no need for a boot directory which holds later stages of the bootloader and several older kernels because the developers wanted to get rid of as many components from the traditional boot process as they could to simplify and [speed up booting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTFfl7AjNfI).

My router running LEDE/OpenWrt doesn't have a /boot directory either.

Answer (score 1):

There's no /boot. ChromeOS uses U-boot (not grub) and has at least 3 kernels and "boot" partitions at a time:
The [disk format](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/disk-format) document has a lot more detail.